# Kotlin empty global variable list out of the function

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have a simple problem.I want to access the list from outside the Call function of the retrofit. But the list appears to be full only in the onResponse method and I can see its contents. If I try to access it from outside the Call method, it returns empty.

```
var liste: List<TumKonumlarCevap> = emptyList()
@Composable
fun KonumuGoster() { 
    val daoInterface = ApiUtils.getDaoInterface()
    daoInterface.konumlariAl().enqueue(object : Callback<List<TumKonumlarCevap>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<TumKonumlarCevap>>,
            response: Response<List<TumKonumlarCevap>>
        ) {
            liste = response.body()

            **//if i test my list here . it turn not empty and show list**

         
            for (k in liste) {
                Log.e("konum", "---------")
                Log.e("konum", k.kid.toString())
                Log.e("konum", k.klat.toString())
                Log.e("konum", k.klong.toString())
            }

        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<TumKonumlarCevap>>, t: Throwable) {

        }

    })

    //  But if i test my list here . it will turn empty

    if(liste.isEmpty()){
        Log.d("liste","Empty")    // TURN EMPTY
    }else{
        Log.d("liste","Not Empty")
    }
   

}
```

Comment: Your code creates an empty list, and queues up a network call that will finish *later* and put stuff in the list. Then it prints the still-empty list - the network call probably hasn't even started yet, it's definitely not finished. And the ``onResponse`` callback (which adds data to the list) only runs when the response comes back. You see this callback pattern a lot - the method that sets up the callback pretty much never has access to the results of that callback, because they usually arrive later. That's why there's a callback!

Comment: Firstly , thanks for answer my question.I understood what you mean.Is it true, network call occur asynchronous , so i need fill my list after finished network call.How can i return my list after response finished and fill my list in response method.

Comment: You can't really "return" it, because nothing asked for it - the callback just says "here's your `response`, now do something with it". Usually your callback function would do something with the data, like calling a function on your ``Fragment`` that displays a list that you pass in. It really depends what you're doing - like in this tutorial (https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23) they're calling a function that displays the data in a `RecyclerView`. It's a big topic with lots of options, so maybe look at some Retrofit tutorials and get the basic idea